# SharePoint Online Communication-Image Gallery-Carousel-Hyperlink

Tags: sharepoint-online, image-display, communication-site

I was wondering whether it is possible to add a hyperlink to each Image in the Image Carousel. So far, I find no place to add a hyperlink. I tried adding an href tag under Caption but it does not work.

[image]

Kindly help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the [Image Gallery web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-image-gallery-web-part-bbcbe560-14a7-4369-8ef5-3255845e3bfd) does not support enhance the images with hyperlinks. Using it, we can only display images on the page.

The [Image web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-image-web-part-a63b335b-ad0a-4954-a65d-33c6af68beb2) allows users to add hyperlinks, but we can display one image with link with one Image web part.

You can use the [Quick Links web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-quick-links-web-part-e1df7561-209d-4362-96d4-469f85ab2a82). You can choice custom image for each link. However, it does not have Carousel layout.

[image]

As an alternative to display images with links in Bootstrap Carousel format, you can use [react-script-editor(SPFx web part)](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to insert html/JavaScript to the page, or [develop custom SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

Besides, you can give a feedback for Image Gallery web part to [SharePoint UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/). 
UserVoice is a platform for getting thoughts about Microsoft Office products.